Decryption tag creation
I am just surprised this tag has not already been created. I would have assumed decryption/unencryption or something similar would have been created. 

Do you have some example questions where you would put it?

Related discussion on the stackoverflow meta: Should “decryption” tag be synonymous with “encryption”?

I added a second sentence to [tag:encryption]'s tag wiki excerpt, though that tag's wiki could get some more text (or text at all).

Personally, I’m not sure if that would really make sense.
Encryption and decryption tend to go hand-in-hand. I have yet to see a question that purely handles decryption without including, at least for some part, encryption too.
And those few questions that purely focus on decryption, tend to use more specific tags like:

distributed-decryption
(currently: 5 questions, of which 1 closed and 1 duplicate of another question.)
decryption-oracle
(currently: 4 questions.)

Therefore, I tend to vote against creating a (rather general) “decryption” tag. I don’t see the need for it.
Yet, that’s merely my personal opinion… others might disagree, and maybe even be able to change my current perspective by providing a good reason why that tag should be created nevertheless.
